# jQuery adjacent sibling selector doesn't traverse correctly

Tags: jquery

Guys I'm having a problem on traversing with `jQuery` what I'm doing is there is 2 `<a>` elements, both `anchor` elements have a same `<div>` element and by default these `<div>` have a property called `display:none`. When I click on  any `anchor` element the `<div>` element is `slideToggle`. But after clicking one `anchor` element, previous `anchor` element `<div>` is `slideUp`  . It's work fine but when i first click second `anchor` element, then click first `anchor`,  second `anchor` element `<div>` is not `slideUp`.

```js
  $('.labels').click(function () {

        $(this).next().stop().slideToggle();
        $(this).prev().stop().slideUp();

    });
```

```css
.content{
border:1px solid black;
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>None</title>
</head>
<body>
<a class="labels">
    <p>Click Label One</p>
</a>
<div class="content">
    <p>Tea</p>
</div>
<a class="labels">
    <p>Click Label Two</p>
</a>
<div class="content">
    <p>Coffee</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because `.prev()` do not traverse to last element. To achieve this you need to remove the color from all `.content` element first and then set color red to next sibling:

```js
var $content = $('.content');
$('.labels').click(function () {
    $content.stop().slideUp();
    $(this).next().stop().slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.content{
border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>None</title>
</head>
<body>
<a class="labels">
    <p>Click Label One</p>
</a>
<div class="content">
    <p>Tea</p>
</div>
<a class="labels">
    <p>Click Label Two</p>
</a>
<div class="content">
    <p>Coffee</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because your logic is flawed. When you click the first `a` element, there is no `prev()` element to set `slideUp()`. To fix this you can select all `.content` elements and call `slideUp()` on them before calling `slideDown()` on the one which was clicked. Try this:

```js
$('.labels').click(function() {
  $('.content').stop().slideUp();
  $(this).next('.content').stop().slideDown();
});
```

```css
.content { 
  border: 1px solid black; 
  display: none;
}
.active { color: #F00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="labels">
  <p>Click Label One</p>
</a>
<div class="content">
  <p>Tea</p>
</div>

<a class="labels">
  <p>Click Label Two</p>
</a>
<div class="content">
  <p>Coffee</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is still the same... just call `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` over the add/removeClass